# How do I get divs to resize according to grid-row and grid-column in css?

Tags: html, css, grid, resize

I want to create a grid for a picture gallery, but when I use the `grid-row` and `grid-column` CSS properties to define the area of the elements in the grid container, it makes them take up two squares either vertically or horizontally. It frees up the space but the grid itself remains in one square. How do I span `grid-columns` and `grid-rows`?

P.S. `grid-row-start`/`grid-row-end` and `grid-column-start`/`grid-column-end` give the same result.

##### HTML

```html
<div id="gallery_pics">
    <div class="gallery_pic">1</div>
    <div class="gallery_pic">2</div>
    <div class="gallery_pic">3</div>
    <div class="gallery_pic">4</div>
    <div class="gallery_pic">5</div>
    <div class="gallery_pic">6</div>
</div>
```

##### CSS

```css
#gallery_pics{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    gap: 10px;
}
.gallery_pic{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background-color: rgb(142, 142, 255);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(1){
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 1/1;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(2){
    grid-row: 1/1;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(3){
    grid-row: 2/2;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(4){
    grid-row: 3/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(5){
    grid-row: 4/4;
    grid-column: 1/2;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(6){
    grid-row: 3/4;
    grid-column: 3/3;
}
```

[This picture with the blue rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edzjg.png) is what I want, and [this image with the red rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpP1i.png) is what I get.

How do I obtain the layout with the blue rectangles instead of that with the red rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

Use the inspector in Firefox or Chrome. You can turn on show grid lines, and it will help you to see what is actually happening.

You were pretty close, but you were one grid line short on all of your spans. Spanning grid column 1 and 2 means going from grid lines 1 to 3. Additionally, if you want to go to the last row or last column, you can use `-1`. So spanning from column two to the end would look like `grid-column: 2 / -1;`

```css
#gallery_pics {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
}
.gallery_pic {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: rgb(142, 142, 255);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/1;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1/1;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 2/2;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 3/3;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 4/4;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.gallery_pic:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 3/-1;
  grid-column: 3/3;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery_pics">
  <div class="gallery_pic">1</div>
  <div class="gallery_pic">2</div>
  <div class="gallery_pic">3</div>
  <div class="gallery_pic">4</div>
  <div class="gallery_pic">5</div>
  <div class="gallery_pic">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
instead of writing

```
grid-row : 1/2;
```

I had to write

```
grid-row : 1/span 2;
```

to specify that it spans from one to two

Comment: This works, but make sure you understand how grid and the grid lines work. Your `grid-row : 1/span 2;` means start at row 1 and span two rows, not to the end of row 2. Look into how the dev-tools in your browser can show the grid lines and grid areas.